# Get values from xml nodes within sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database

I have string data with xml format in "Input" column from which I need specific values of nodes.

As an example:

I need every "error_text_1" value from each "error id".

```
<error_protokoll>

<header>  
 <source>machine</source> 
</header>

<error_list>

 <error id='0'>
   <error_text_1>error0</error_text_1> 
 </error>

 <error id='1'>
   <error_text_1>error1</error_text_1>
 </error>

</error_list>

</error_protokoll>
```

The following sql statement returns only the "error_text_1" value of id=0.

```
SELECT top (10)

XML_INPUT.value('(error_protokoll/error_list/error/error_text_1)[1]', 'varchar(200)') error

FROM 
(
 convert(xml, SUBSTRING( REPLACE(INPUT, '{
 "xml" : "<?xml version=''1.0''?>', ''), 0 , len(REPLACE(INPUT, '{
 "xml" : "<?xml version=''1.0''?>', ''))-3)) as XML_INPUT

 FROM  [Storage].[ods].[table]

) a
```

Instead of only the first item, I'd like to have all of them.

Could you please help how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like you have JSON containing XML, perhaps you should use `OPENJSON` or `JSON_VALUE` to retrieve it. Also not sure why you are removing the `<?xml` preamble, it's supposed to be there. Please give a [mcve] containing the *actual* value you need to convert

Comment: @Charlieface, I edited the original post to show the original cell value which is in the Input column. Because of the "{ }" brackets and ""xml" : "<?xml version=''1.0''?>" I convert the text into xml.

Comment: I have rolled back that edit, as it invalidates my existing answer; this is severely frowned upon by the community. [Don't be a Chameleon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332820/2029983).

Comment: Looks like `CAST(JSON_VALUE(yourValue, '$.xml') AS xml)` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `nodes` in the `FROM` so that you get 1 row per `error` element, then you can get the value of `error_text_1` for each one:

```sql
DECLARE @xml xml = '<error_protokoll>
    <header>
        <source>machine</source>
    </header>
    <error_list>
        <error id="0">
            <error_text_1>error0</error_text_1>
        </error>
        <error id="1">
            <error_text_1>error1</error_text_1>
        </error>
    </error_list>
</error_protokoll>';

SELECT X.e.value('(./error_text_1/text())[1]','varchar(200)') AS error_text_1
FROM @xml.nodes('error_protokoll/error_list/error')X(e);
```

If the XML is in a table, your `FROM` would look like:

```sql
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY YT.YourColumn.nodes('error_protokoll/error_list/error')YC(e);
```

Comment: the problem is that I need first to convert string to xml, so I need to use your recommendation within the original statement, doing something like this: SELECT top (10)

YC.e.value('(./error_text_1/text())[1]','varchar(200)') error_tesxt_1

FROM  (
 select 
 cross apply convert(xml, SUBSTRING( REPLACE(INPUT, '{
  "xml" : "<?xml version=''1.0''?>', ''), 0 , len(REPLACE(INPUT, '{
  "xml" : "<?xml version=''1.0''?>', ''))-3)).nodes('error_protokoll/error_list/error')YC(e)
FROM  [Storage].[ods].[table]

) b

Comment: *"the problem is that I need first to convert string to xml"* Why isn't your XML not `xml` in the first place, @Kristan ? That there is your problem. If you want to parse XML in T-SQL, then it needs to be `xml`.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right but unfotunately here is some other information which violates the xml structure thus first I need to preprocess and convert it to xml. The "XML_INPUT" finally hass the right structure but with this I can only get single values as shown in the oiginal code, @Larnu.

Comment: The XML in your question is valid XML, @Kristan . If you have XML stored as a `(n)varchar` that isn't valid XML, and you want to convert it to valid XML that is a **different** question; you'll need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), with examples of the malformed XML. Though SQL Server's string manipulation is poor at best. You *need* to fix your data, and most likely that needs to be done at source.

Comment: I edited the original post to show you how the cell value looks like in the Input column. That is why I make the xml conversion at first place.

Comment: Please don't edit a question to invalidate existing answers, @Kristan . If the question has changed, ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).